# Build error caused by missing library arc4random

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, cygwin, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I'm currently working on a Streaming framework, and decided to use ffmpeg to encode and or decode my Video and or Audio.

So i clicked through https://ffmpeg.org for the api files, and downloaded the statically linked version only to find out it actually contained a .exe (I use Windows in development, but plan on using Linux in production) instead of one or more dll's and header informations.

Since i don't think i can use the 'exe' as replacement for an dll, i cloned the git source, and tried to compile it myself.

Then, while compiling i run into this error:

```
CC  libavutil/random_seed.o
libavutil/random_seed.c: In function 'av_get_random_seed':
libavutil/random_seed.c:130:12: error: implicit declaration of function 'arc4random' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
     return arc4random();
            ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
common.mak:60: recipe for target 'libavutil/random_seed.o' failed
make: *** [libavutil/random_seed.o] Error 1
```

As far as I can tell, this means that I'm missing the library arc4random, so I started searching for this lib, and found absolutly nothing, besides the fact that this library is somehow Apple related..., but no dll's and stuff or sources to compile it myself.

I use cygwin and its GCC to compile on 64-Bit windows 7 Machine.

Can anyone hint me to some location where I can get this missing library, or some other possibility to get ffmpeg as library into my project?
(I would prefer something I can link statically , since this project is meant to be a lib by itself)

Maybe is there a way I can make use of that downloaded exe of ffmpeg, since i can borrow its headers from the source I cloned from Git?

Any Hint appreciated.

Best Regards,

Jannik Adam

Comment: have you installed the `cygwin-devel` package ?

Comment: @matzeri yes, version 2.5.1-1

Comment: I got the same error too. The only potential useful info I found was patches for arc4random.c, I don't know if perhaps patches need applying before compiling.

Comment: In addition you could obtain ffmpeg via cygwinports https://github.com/cygwinports/cygport. Easy install instructions can be found here: http://cygwinports.org/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be caused because the `#if` is incorrectly reporting that the system has this function. I was able to get around it by editing a couple of files.

Open `libavutil/random_seed.c` and look for `#if HAVE_ARC4RANDOM`, should be around line 129, and remove that block of three lines:

```
129 #if HAVE_ARC4RANDOM
130     return arc4random();
131 #endif
```

When you run make again you'll probably get another similar failure in time.c for gettimeofday(), so open `libavutil/time.c` and look for `#if HAVE_GETTIMEOFDAY` which should be around line 41 and remove the first block there, like this:

Before changing:

```
41 #if HAVE_GETTIMEOFDAY
42     struct timeval tv;
43     gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
44     return (int64_t)tv.tv_sec * 1000000 + tv.tv_usec;
45 #elif HAVE_GETSYSTEMTIMEASFILETIME
```

After changing:

```
41 #if HAVE_GETSYSTEMTIMEASFILETIME
```

After those two changes the compile got a lot further but failed on ffserver.c:

```
ffserver.c: In function ‘main’:
ffserver.c:4000:5: error: implicit declaration of function ‘sigaction’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
     sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sigact, 0);
```

To fix this error I opened config.mak and added `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700` to the end of CFLAGS, like this:

```
42 CFLAGS=   -std=c99 -fomit-frame-pointer -pthread  -g -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wall -Wdisabled-optimization -Wpointer-arith -Wredundant-decls -Wwrite-strings -Wtype-limits -Wundef -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-pointer-to-int-cast -Wstrict-prototypes -Wempty-body -Wno-parentheses -Wno-switch -Wno-format-zero-length -Wno-pointer-sign -O3 -fno-math-errno -fno-signed-zeros -Werror=format-security -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Werror=missing-prototypes -Werror=return-type -Werror=vla -Wformat -fdiagnostics-color=auto -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118447/compilation-error-of-c-code-on-linux-same-code-compiles-on-osx) explains a bit about why `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700` helps.

Then I ran `make` again and it finally succeeded. After running `make install` all the binaries were put in place and I was able to successfully use it!

Comment: For me the solution worked without changes in time.c file

Comment: is configure detecting HAVE_ARC4RANDOM in error here, or what causes the initial problem I wonder...